# Не работает кириллица при построении проекта в eclipse и netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, utf-8, кириллица

При компиляции выводит нормально, а после построения вот такое. Причём, везде стоит UTF-8 (И NB и Eclipse). Нашёл решение - создать bat-файл, который запустит jar UTF-8 кодировке, это помогает, но возможно ли обойтись без этого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Windows 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках проекта и в Netbeans и в Eclipse есть возможность настройки запуска приложений. Добавьте туда параметр запуска с кодировкой, и все дела.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант поставить IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition там по больше настроек по кодировки, плюс есть поддержка конвертации при смене ее в проекте. в случае отрицательного результата, думаю стоит копать в сторону плохой или отсутствие кодировки 1251-1252 (точно не помню какую) :) в виндовсе... Когда то была похожая проблема.